# Невозможно виджету задать новый поток

Tags: qt, многопоточность

Создал проект с файлом .ui в котором  скомпоновано по горизонтали два QTableWidget-a. Проект перекрестно собирается программа работает  но во время работы  выдаёт.

```
QObject::moveToThread: Widgets cannot be moved to a new thread
```

Я пытался в один из QTableWidget-ов, складывать информацию которая обрабатывается  в отдельном потоке. НО почему то сам Qt этого не позволяет. Почему? Как это обойти ???

Вот еще вывод приложения:

```
Запускается D:\k....iewUi.exe...
QObject::moveToThread: Widgets cannot be moved to a new thread
Receiving_a_Message()
D:/k....iewUi.exe завершился с кодом 0
```

---

Я посмотрел варианты и заметил . Что не могу перемещать виджеты из за того что они зарезервированы главным потоком что бы интерфейс был отзывчивым и по этому GUI  и должен находиться в главном потоке.

Для того что бы решить это проблему надо не на прямую отправлять (один из QTableWidget-ов), а возвращать в главный поток информацию.

Но я  не знаю как это сделать ? (все что в голову приходит работать через структуры, но как приказать программе перерисовать виджет когда я его накидал в редакторе "при этом постоянно " ????)

Comment: А зачем вам отдельный поток? Если вам нужно в потоке заполнять таблицу, тогда, одним из вариантом -- создать класс из QThread, переопределить метод run, в классе создать нужный вам сигнал и из run вызывать сигнал. Это будет поток. Останется его создать, запустить и тот сигнал подсоединить к нужной функции, которая вытащить информацию и что-то сделает с таблицей. У меня есть пример такого на python qt: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/c7c6d5a70116bc713d54eab871638245c9645e7c/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/qt__qtablewidget_fill_from_thread__with_api.py

Comment: @gil9red переопределение метода run() самый не понятный и очень не ликвидный метод (ни примеров ни смысла зачем это, я так и не увидел )

Comment: Примеры и смыслы легко гуглятся. Но мне не сложно объяснить. Когда вы вызываете у потока метод `start`, тот вызывает у себя метод `run`. Если переопределять qt-поток, то нужно переопределять метод `run`. В моем примере в `run` выполняется бесконечный цикл, которые раз в n-секунд выполняется и по сигналу посылает данные в основной поток. Другой способ работы с потоками -- отправка объекта в указанный поток. Оба способами работы с потоками работают, но породили "святые войны". Мне больше вариант с переопределением потока нравится. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details

Comment: @gil9red перегрузка очень сложна для восприятия (непонятно). Вы не совсем поняли вопроса если элементы накидать в UI дизайнере то работать с элементами gui из иных потоков не возможно,  а как работать с главным тоже непонятно . Код  у меня работает если я все элементы сделал руками.

Comment: Наследование и перегрузка основа ОПП. Если вам она сложна, стоит больше тренироваться. Вот простой банальный пример -- наследование от QWidget и переопределение paintEvent'а чтобы рисовать на виджете через QPainter. Если код у вас работает, тогда в чем проблема? :)

Comment: Ответ на вопрос находиться [здесь(с полным кодом и комментариями)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/837751/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80-qt-creator-a-%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: Молодец, что разобрались :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в то что я главный поток перекинул в 'отдельный' поток. А этого делать нельзя

**Было**

```
    QThread *thread = new QThread();  
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(Receiving_a_Message())); 
    connect(this,SIGNAL(update_m(int)),this,SLOT(RepaintReceivedMessage(int)));  
    this->moveToThread(thread); // отправляем в поток
    thread->start(); // цикл обработки сообщения в потоке
```

**Стало**

```
    QThread *thread = new QThread(); 
    MyThread_priem *mythread_priem = new MyThread_priem();

    connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), mythread_priem, SLOT(Receiving_a_Message())); 
    connect(mythread_priem, SIGNAL(update_m(int)), this, SLOT(RepaintReceivedMessage(int))); 

    mythread_priem->moveToThread(thread); // отправляем в поток
    thread->start();
```

[Более подробно и с комментариями тут.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/837751/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80-qt-creator-a-%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)