# Дизайнер Qt Creator-a и многопоточность, как их подружить

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность

В общем столкнулся с проблемой, если внешний вид программы сделал в дизайнере qt creator-a, то не получаться сделать несколько потоков и взаимодействовать  с GUI интерфейсом.  Если внешний вид программы написать "руками" в виде кода, без использования дизайнера qt creator-a то получаеться сделать несколько потоков и взаимодействовать  с GUI интерфейсом ))). 
Но так как у меня проделана большая работа в в дизайнере qt creator-a, то я  бы не хотел бы перерисовать все с нуля.

По этому я сделал простейший пример, как я делаю. Хотелось бы услышать конструктивную критику и реальный код как надо делать.

*Простейшая программа которая выводит на QspinBox постоянно число из бесконечного цикла.*

*SimpleGUItwoflow.pro*

```
QT       += core gui serialbus widgets concurrent

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = SimpleGUItwoflow
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui
```

*mainwindow.h*

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
signals:
    void update_m(int);

public slots:
    void RepaintReceivedMessage(int i);  
    void Receiving_a_Message();  

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

*mainwindow.cpp*

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // поток приёма данных
    QThread *thread = new QThread(); // инициализ класс потока
    MyThread_priem *mythread_priem = new MyThread_priem(); // инициализируем второй класс

    connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(Receiving_a_Message())); // наследуем thread  а не от MyMainWindows-a
    connect(this,SIGNAL(update_m(int)),this,SLOT(RepaintReceivedMessage(int))); // соединение источника данных с приемником

    this->moveToThread(thread); // отправляем в поток
    thread->start(); // цикл обработки сообщения в потоке0
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::Receiving_a_Message()
{
    qDebug() << "Receiving_a_Message()";

    while (true) {
        for (int i =0; i<1000000;i++){

            qDebug() << "i: " << i;

            emit update_m(i);
        }
    }
}

void MainWindow::RepaintReceivedMessage(int i)
{
    ////
     qDebug() << "RepaintReceivedMessage()";
     ui->spinBox->setValue(i);
}
```

*mainwindow.ui*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**А вот и результат :** 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Программа работает но GUI не отвечает. При этом программа не падает.

---

Исправил код 
.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
signals:

public slots:
     void RepaintReceivedMessage(int);   

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

class MyThread_priem: public QObject{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    void Clear_Struct();

private:

signals:
 void update_m(int);

public slots:
    void Receiving_a_Message();  

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

.срр
    #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include "ui_mainwindow.h"

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // поток приёма данных
    QThread *thread = new QThread(); 
    MyThread_priem *mythread_priem = new MyThread_priem(); 

    connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), mythread_priem, SLOT(Receiving_a_Message())); 
    connect(mythread_priem, SIGNAL(update_m()), this, SLOT(RepaintReceivedMessage())); 

    mythread_priem->moveToThread(thread); 
    thread->start(); 
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MyThread_priem::Receiving_a_Message()
{
    qDebug() << "Receiving_a_Message()";

    while (true) {
        for (int i =0; i<1000000;i++){

            qDebug() << "i: " << i;

            emit update_m(i);
        }
    }
}


void MainWindow::RepaintReceivedMessage(int i)
{
    ////
     qDebug() << "RepaintReceivedMessage()";
     ui->spinBox->setValue(i);
}
```

Отправил в отдельный поток, но всё равно он не меняет значения spinBox-а

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: какая-то лажа — код бессмысленный... как в нём и написано  основной поток после старта второго (который ничего не делает) весит в цикле в `MainWindow::Receiving_a_Message`... лучше посмотри какие-нить примеры, из комплекта кьюта

Comment: @Fat-Zer не понял сообщения

Comment: *ixSci* уже всё расписал подробней... я не заметил что там есть `movetoThread ()` (и в таком варианте это выглядит ещё хуже)... так что  напомню, что **вся** работа с гуйнёй должна происходить из одного, главного потока.

Comment: @Fat-Zer всё равно воспользовавшись предложенным методом, не сработал  QspinBox

Comment: У вас сигналы слишком часто отправляются, гуй будет не успевать перерисовываться и будет так же подвисать. Ошибка, которую вы допустили в коде, является иллюстрацией того, почему лучше использовать новый синтаксис соединений.

Comment: @BeardedBeaver  я со старым справиться не могу а вы мне про новый говорите ))  (можно за счет, пауз сделать чтоб он успевал отобразиться)

Comment: @BeardedBeaver а есть ли нормально разложенная статья про QtConcurrent ? А то по простому "очень сложно" я просто не разобрался а простейших примеров считай нету.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас не код, а кошмар. Начнём с того, что вот это `this->moveToThread(thread);` является рассадником проблем, поэтому `this` не надо никогда перемещать в другой поток. Читайте статьи по правильному использованию `QThread`, начать можно с [You’re doing it wrong…](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/).

Ну а *конкретная* проблема в Вашем коде в том, что у Вас `MainWindow` живёт вне UI потока (Вы его сами переместили), и в коде этого окна вызывается `ui->spinBox->setValue(i);`, что запрещено делать вне потока UI.

Comment: всё равно воспользовавшись предложенным методом, не сработал  QspinBox

Comment: @timob256, как Вы думаете, что я должен понять из Вашего комментария? Вы бы хоть в вопрос добавили новый код... В целом же я указал на ошибки, остальное можно найти самостоятельно экспериментируя.

Answer (score 0):

Вот код, всё работает.

**.pro** не менялся

**.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>


namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
signals:
public slots:
    void RepaintReceivedMessage(int);
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

class MyThread_priem: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    void Clear_Struct();
private:
signals:
    void update_m(int);
public slots:
    void Receiving_a_Message();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QThread *thread = new QThread(); 
    MyThread_priem *mythread_priem = new MyThread_priem();

    connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), mythread_priem, SLOT(Receiving_a_Message())); 
    connect(mythread_priem, SIGNAL(update_m(int)), this, SLOT(RepaintReceivedMessage(int))); 

    mythread_priem->moveToThread(thread); // отправляем в поток
    thread->start(); 
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MyThread_priem::Receiving_a_Message()
{
    qDebug() << "Receiving_a_Message()";

    while (true) {
        for (int i =0; i<100000;i++){

            qDebug() << "i: " << i;

            emit update_m(i);
        }
    }
}

void MainWindow::RepaintReceivedMessage(int i)
{
     qDebug() << "RepaintReceivedMessage()";
     ui->spinBox->setValue(i);
}
```

**.ui** не менялся

**main.cpp** не менялся